# component injection to symfony 3 Session

Tags: php, symfony, session

Maybe someone can help me

I am not familiar with symfony.
There is running Symfony 3.3.9 with Smarty 3.1.27

I want to inject something to the Session Handling, so each time session is started with

`new Session()` or

```
$session = $this->container->get('session');
```

different session values are given

for example

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Components;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\SessionStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

class MDSession extends Session {

private $domain     =   null;

private $mandant    =   null;

const DEFAULT_THEME = '_default';



    public function __construct(SessionStorageInterface $storage = null,AttributeBagInterface $attributes = null,FlashBagInterface $flashes = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($storage, $attributes, $flashes);

        $this->getDomain();

        /**
         * check if session is set and the same requested domain given
         */
        if(!$this->_get('domain') || $this->_get('domain') != $this->domain)
        {

            $this->mandant = $this->getMandant();

            /**
             * set session here
             */
            $this->_set('domain',   $this->domain);
            $this->_set('mandant',  $this->mandant['id']);
            $this->_set('theme',    $this->mandant['theme']);
        }
    }

    public function _set($name=null,$value=null)
    {
        parent::set($name,$value);
    }

    public function _get($name)
    {
        parent::get($name);
    }


    /**
     * HostnameLookups must be set to On in Apache
     */
    private function getDomain()
    {
        $this->domain = strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
    }

    private function getMandant()
    {
         /**
         * do something here
         */
    }
}
```

How to set config.yml or services.yml to get it working ?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear at all

Comment: this what happened in class MDSession above, should automatically done, if Session is started with

$session = $this->container->get('session');

Comment: This is probably a case where you are trying to apply old habits to a new framework.  Assuming that you are using the actual Symfony framework (and not just a few components) then a kernel listener would typically be used to inject this sort of stuff before the session gets to the controller: http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html.  And pulling data directly from $_SERVER is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thx. For better understanding. Can you show me, how the listener would look like, where I check and set the session field ?

Answer (score 0):

at the moment I do it with an EventListener like this.

I hope this is the right way

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;


class SessionHandler
{

    const DEFAULT_THEME = '_default';

    const DEFAULT_MANDANT = '1';


    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request    = $event->getRequest();
        $session    = $request->getSession();
        $host       = $request->getHost();

        if(!empty($session->get('mandant')) OR $session->get('host') != $host)
        {

            //check DB for mandant

            //.....

            //setting session
            $session->set('host',       $host);
            $session->set('mandant',    self::DEFAULT_MANDANT);
            $session->set('theme',      self::DEFAULT_THEME);
        }


        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            // don't do anything if it's not the master request
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```